# Meaning and usage of jquery find('>')

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm working on a javascript code which does :

**`$('div').html(<some text>).find('>')`**

Looking at the jQuery documentation, I can't understand what `find('>')` is supposed to do.

Moreover, when experimenting in navigator console, I get strange results :

`$('div').html('to<br/>to').find('>')` -> `[ <br>​, <br>​, <br>​]`

`$('div').html('to<a/>to').find('>')` -> `[ <a>​</a>​, <a>​</a>​, <a>​</a>​]`

Why a 3 times repetiton ?

So, can anyone enlighten me about this strange `find('>')` ?

Comment: Probably all direct descendants

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/. It accomplishing the same as [`.children()`](http://api.jquery.com/children/).

Comment: *Why a 3 times repetiton ?* Maybe because you have 3 divs? http://jsfiddle.net/tBq5U/

Comment: It should be noted that you should avoid using it `find('>')` and ya use `children()` instead

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon I'm really not used to jquery... I thought the line was *creating* a div then setting some html into it.

Comment: @Offirmo to create a DIV, you need: `$('<div/>')`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`>` is the [Child Combinator CSS selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#child-combinators). `.find('>')` will pull all direct children of the element.

As mentioned in comments, the repetitions must be due to your document having multiple `div` elements.

#### Update

From [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22537216/meaning-and-usage-of-jquery-find/22537303#comment34297577_22537216):

> I thought the line was creating a div then setting some html into it.

`$('div')` itself selects all `div` elements which exist within document. If you want to create a `div` element, you can instead do this:

```
$('<div/>', { html: 'to<br/>to' });
```

If you're new to jQuery, I'd strongly advise checking out http://try.jquery.com and http://learn.jquery.com.

Comment: Thanks. I missed this selector. Now can you explain the repetitions ?

Comment: Your repetitions originate from your selector, @Offirmo. `$('div')` will be selecting 3 `divs`. You then take those `div` elements and set their innerHTML to contain one element, which `find` then returns and combines.

Comment: @offirmo, `$('<div>')` is not the same as `$('div')`. Are you saying you are getting the repetition as well if you use the former.

Answer (score 3):

As someone pointed out, '>' selects the child elements of an element.

Why 3? Because surely you have 3 divs, so

```
$('div')        //selects 3 divs
   .html(...)   // adds content to each div
   .find('>');  //return the direct descendants of each element in the jQuery object 
                //as a new jQuery object
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation of each part. I thought the code was creating a div.

Comment: The `div` already exists. You are adding content to the `div`.